# Get derivative of data in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, derivative

I write a program to get derivative. InterpolatedUnivariateSpline is used for calculating f(x+h). The red line is derivative of cosine, the green line is cosine consine, the blue line is -sine function. The red and blue line are matched. It works well in the following.

[image: Result]

```
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pi = np.pi
x = np.arange(0,5*pi,0.2*pi)
y = np.cos(x) 
f2 = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)
#Get dervative
der = []
for i in range(len(y)):

    h = 1e-4
    der.append( ( f2(x[i]+h)-f2(x[i]-h) )/(2*h) )
der = np.array(der)   

plt.plot(x, der, 'r', x, y, 'g', x, -np.sin(x),'b')
plt.show()
```

But I encounter some problem. In my project, my variable x(frequency) vary from 10^7 to 2.2812375*10^9, its step is 22487500,so I change array x.
As a result, I get the following result.

[image: Result2]

The derivative is a line and almost close to 0, It is not -sine function. How do I solve this?

Comment: ```InterpolatedUnivariateSpline``` has a [```derivitive```](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.derivative.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.derivative) method. Is there a reason you are not using it?

Comment: It seems like a [loss of significance problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance). You could divide `x` by something like `1e7` or increase `h` to something around the magnitude of `1e5`. Also if `x` has high enough resolution a simpler to numerically differentiate the function would be `dy = np.diff(y) / np.diff(x)`. This way you do not have to worry about setting `h`.

Comment: Hi! wwii, I also try derivitive in InterpolatedUnivariateSpline, It get the same  result below.

Comment: Yes! I divide x by 1e9 to get derivative right. Also dy = np.diff(y) / np.diff(x) can works well, But I  need to adjust length of x.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Comment: I converted my comment into a proper answer to adhere to the guidelines.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your answer! I am worried about this page will be deleted if there is no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) problem. It means that when adding a large  floating point number to a small one, the precision of the small one is partially lost as a numpy double can only hold 64 bits of information.

To solve this issue you have to make sure that the scale of the numbers you add/multiply/divide is not too different. One simple solution is dividing `x` by `1e9` or multiplying `h` by `1e9`. If you do this you get essentially the same precision as in your example.

Also if `x` has high enough resolution a simpler way to numerically differentiate the function would be `der = np.diff(y) / np.diff(x)`. This way you do not have to worry about setting h. However in this case note that `dy` is one element shorter that `y`, and `dy[i]` is actually an approximation of the derivative at `(x[i] + x[i+1]) / 2. So to plot it you would do:

```
der = np.diff(y) / np.diff(x)
x2 = (x[:-1] + x[1:]) / 2
plt.plot(x2, der, 'r', x, y, 'g', x, -np.sin(x),'b')
```

Comment: I try multiplying h by 1e9, but it can't solve loss of significance.

Answer (score 1):

Show my plots using np. gradient()

[image]

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pi = np.pi
x = np.arange(0,5*pi,0.2*pi)
y = np.cos(x) 
der = np.gradient(y,x)
plt.plot(x, der, 'r', x, y, 'g', x, -np.sin(x),'b')
plt.show()
```

I can smooth the plots using spline. If you need, I will post.

Comment: It seems like your answer has some formatting issues. It contains several appearances of `enter code here`. Please review your answer and probably fix that. FYI: inline statements wrapped into backticks ` are formatted into code.